# Microsoft Teams subscription call

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

So I want to receive a notification, when a call is happening `callRecord (/communications/callRecords)` so I grabed myself [this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-changenotifications/tree/master/demos/03-track-changes) example and changed the task function to this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Get()
        {
            var graphServiceClient = GetGraphClient();

            var sub = new Microsoft.Graph.Subscription();
            sub.ChangeType = "created";
            sub.NotificationUrl = config.Ngrok + "/api/notifications";
            sub.Resource = "/communications/callRecords";
            sub.ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5);

            var newSubscription = await graphServiceClient
              .Subscriptions
              .Request()
              .AddAsync(sub);

            Subscriptions[newSubscription.Id] = newSubscription;

            if (subscriptionTimer == null)
            {
                subscriptionTimer = new Timer(CheckSubscriptions, null, 5000, 15000);
            }

            return $"Subscribed. Id: {newSubscription.Id}, Expiration: {newSubscription.ExpirationDateTime}";
        }
```

I also added the graph api permission `CallRecords.Read.All` to my app. Beforehand I testet the example with the updated users notification and it worked fine. But now it won't trigger the notification for a call.

Comment: What response do you get when you create the subscription? Did you see the latency table in the docs? (It was added last week) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks#latency

Comment: I had it running for almost two hours, no subscription call was made to my api. This is what I'm receiving: `Subscribed. Id: ff3e9962-8643-4235-bb14-0bec0f9b3b3f, Expiration: 13.08.2020 13:40:08 +00:00`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same here, everything worked yesterday but today my webhook endpoint didn't even trigger once.

I think there might be an issue on Microsoft's side. I follow this issue [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/9502) of someone who has the same problem as us.

UPDATE: Someone from Microsoft answered in the linked Github Issue:

> There is currently an ongoing issue.
> The related post is TM220340 in the M365 Admin Center.

So they're confirming that the issue is on their end.

Comment: `Comms post should be fixed. You can follow that for updates.` Now it works fine